# Как сделать POST запрос c form-data как в Postman?

Tags: javascript, http, post, fetch

Пытаюсь сделать post запрос с form-data как в Postman, но не удается загрузить изображение(picture).
Сам ответ на запрос в Postmane выглядит так:
[image: Запрос с form-data в Postman]

В ответ сервер выводит созданный объект и в picture занесено сгенирированое название файла.

Значения полей я считываю с инпутов и возвращаю обьект типа FormData:

```
 const readNewValues = (target, _id = null) => {
  let name = target.querySelector(".report__title").value;
  let keyWords = target.querySelector(".report__key-words").value;
  let content = target.querySelector(".report__content").value;
  let picture = target.querySelector(".report__picture").files[0].name;
  let pageCount = target.querySelector(".report__page-count").value;
  let creationDate = target.querySelector(".report__creation-date").value;
  let newFormDataReport = new FormData();
  newFormDataReport.append("_id", _id);
  newFormDataReport.append("name", name);
  newFormDataReport.append("keyWords", keyWords);
  newFormDataReport.append("content", content);
  newFormDataReport.append("picture", picture);
  newFormDataReport.append("pageCount", pageCount);
  newFormDataReport.append("creationDate", creationDate);
  return newFormDataReport;
  
};
```

Затем возвращенный FormData объект я отправляю по запросу:

```
const addNewReport = async (createdReport) => {
  const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/reports`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    body: createdReport,
  });
  const report = await result.json();
  return report;
};
```

На бэкэнд части с помощью обьектов класса ReportController и ReportService считываю данные и заношу в бд:

```
class ReportController {
  create = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const report = await ReportService.create(req.body, req.files.picture);
      res.json(report);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json(error.message);
    }
  };
}

class ReportService {
      create = async (report, picture) => {
        const fileName = FileService.saveFile(picture);
        const createdReport = await Report.create({ ...report, picture: fileName });
        return createdReport;
      };
}
```

Но при попытке отправления POST запроса, получаю ошибку.

[image: Полезная нагрузка]

Comment: Там написано что это **ОТВЕТ**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не совсем понял про какой именно ответ, если что запрос на создание нового объекта выделен красным.

Comment: На скрине вкладка с ответом сервера на запрос.... а не с запросом..на него

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если я вас правильно понял, то уже отредактировал.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov я читал информацию на этом сайте, я могу ошибаться, но я сделал все тоже самое только через fetch и без формы.

Comment: Вместо последнего скрина где на вкладке "Сеть" открыто "Ответ" прикрепите скрин с открытой вкладкой "Полезная нагрузка", потому что информативности в данном случае от вкладки "Ответ" абсолютный ноль, хотелось бы посмотреть что ушло на сервер, а не что Вы получили.

Comment: @Milon777 вы передаете `multipart/form-data`, а в контроллере пытаетесь прочитать как `json`, но мультипарт - это не json

Comment: точней в body пытаетесь передать json

Comment: @Simon добавил.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov я убрал headers в запросе и у меня удалось получить данные, которые я отправлял, но у меня перезагружается страница и данные не добавляются в бд, я не понимаю почему, если у меня даже формы нет на странице которая могла бы перезагружать ее после отправки. Хотя сама картинка сохраняется на компьютере. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что я в сервисе пытаюсь создать обьект рапорта как из обычного обьекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением оказалось добавление обычной формы:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="text" name="keyWords" />
      <input type="text" name="content" />
      <input type="file" name="picture" />
      <input type="text" name="pageCount" />
      <input type="date" name="creationDate" />
      <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Отмена стандартного поведения формы при отправке:

```
 uploadForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

И отправка POST запроса без заголовков:

```
 const addNewReport = async (createdReport) => {
  const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/reports`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: createdReport,
  });
};
```

Как отменить стандартное поведение отправки формы при создании собственной формы вручную через:

```
  let newFormDataReport = new FormData();
  newFormDataReport.append("name", name);
```

Я так и не понял.